# Need help to pass variable from php

Tags: php

Need help:

I already make a latex template for my report. My report needs variable from PHP.
How to make it?

Thank you

Comment: Almost certainly off-topic for this site, since this is fundamentally a PHP problem. Related: [method for creating PHP templates (ie html with variables)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905696/method-for-creating-php-templates-ie-html-with-variables)

Comment: If you can make PHP write a text file called `myvariables.tex`, that contains `\newcommand{\myPHPvariable}{<the number you want>}`, then you can say `\input{myvariables}` in the preamble of your `.tex` file, and write `\myPHPvariable` where you need to use that variable.